# OpenGL exception when trying to assign Framebuffer's Color Attachment to Cubemap's faces

Tags: c++, exception, opengl, textures, framebuffer

I need to create an Environment Map centered in the center of my scene. To do this, I'm using a framebuffer and 6 cameras to render each corner (right, left, top, bottom, back, front).

First, I create the cubemap that will have to contain the final result:

```
unsigned int envMapTex;
glGenTextures(1, &envMapTex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, envMapTex);
const unsigned int ENV_WIDTH = 1024, ENV_HEIGHT = 1024;
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB, ENV_WIDTH, ENV_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
}
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);
```

I create the renderbuffer which will contain only the depth values ​​and which will be assigned to the depth attachment of the framebuffer:

```
unsigned int envMapRBO;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &envMapRBO);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, envMapRBO);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, ENV_WIDTH, ENV_HEIGHT);
```

I create the texture that will have to memorize at each iteration, the perspective from every angle:

```
unsigned int envMapSuppTex;
glGenTextures(1, &envMapSuppTex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, envMapSuppTex);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, ENV_WIDTH, ENV_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

And finally I create and initialize the framebuffer:

```
unsigned int envMapFBO;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &envMapFBO);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, envMapFBO);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, envMapSuppTex, 0);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, envMapRBO);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) std::cout << "yep" << std::endl;
else std::cout << "nope" << std::endl;
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

At this point I create the array of the 6 cameras:

```
float aspect = (float)ENV_WIDTH / (float)ENV_HEIGHT;
float near = 1.0f;
float far = 25.0f;
glm::vec3 center = glm::vec3(0.0f, wall_height / 2.0f, 0.0f);
Camera envMapCameras[6] = {
    Camera(ENV_WIDTH, ENV_HEIGHT, center, 90.0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, near, far), //Positive X
    Camera(ENV_WIDTH, ENV_HEIGHT, center, 90.0, -180.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, near, far), //Negative X
    Camera(ENV_WIDTH, ENV_HEIGHT, center, 90.0, -90.0f, 90.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, near, far), //Positive Y
    Camera(ENV_WIDTH, ENV_HEIGHT, center, 90.0, -90.0f, -90.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, near, far), //Negative Y
    Camera(ENV_WIDTH, ENV_HEIGHT, center, 90.0, 90.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, near, far), //Positive Z
    Camera(ENV_WIDTH, ENV_HEIGHT, center, 90.0, -90.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, near, far), //Negative Z
};
```

In the render loop, at each iteration:

1. I render the scene with a camera
2. I bind the cubemap and the color attachment
3. I assign the current color attachment to the current face of the cubemap
4. The cycle restarts with the next camera

   ```
    if (firstFrame)
    {
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, envMapFBO);
        glViewport(0, 0, ENV_WIDTH, ENV_HEIGHT);
        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        {
            glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
            renderSkybox(*skyboxShader, envMapCameras[i]);
            glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

            glEnable(GL_BLEND);
            glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            renderScene(envMapCameras[i]);

            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, envMapTex);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, envMapSuppTex);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB, ENV_WIDTH, ENV_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &envMapSuppTex);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        }
   ```

When I run, an exception is thrown right after the line:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB, ENV_WIDTH, ENV_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &envMapSuppTex);
```

So the question is: how do I correctly assign the color attachment of a framebuffer to a face of a cubemap?

[image: This is the exception]

P.s.: The exception is reported on the "glBindTexture ..." line, but if I remove/comment that line, the exception moves. In general I am very sure it is relative to the "glTexImage2D..." line.

SOLUTION

Since envMapSuppTex is the ID of a texture in the GPU memory, we cannot use glTexImage2D() because it requires a pointer in the CPU memory. Consequently we use glCopyTexImage2D() to copy the texture to the target of our choice. The texture is copied from the target defined by glReadBuffer() (or glNamedFramebufferReadBuffer()).

In my case:

```
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glCopyTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB, 0, 0, ENV_WIDTH, ENV_HEIGHT, 0);
```

The glTexImage2D() line can be safely removed.

Thanks to Hihikomori for the solution.

Comment: envMapSuppTex - is an id of texture in gpu memory, but glTexImage2D needs a pointer to host memory.

Comment: I would suggest to replace &envMapSuppTex with null pointer  and then copy fbo texture to cube map texture with glCopyTexImage2D.

Comment: @Hihikomori Thanks for the reply! Yes, the problem was that, that envMapSuppTex was an ID of a texture in the GPU memory. Using glReadBuffer() and glCopyTexImage2D() solves the problem. Now I edit the post with the solution.